# AjaxControlToolKit: HTML Editor (Unknown Server Tag)

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, html-editor

I am going to add the HTML editor and the code is following

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>
    <%@ Register TagPrefix="asp" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"%>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
  <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="Server" />

        <asp:TextBox
        ID="txtComments"
        TextMode="MultiLine"
        Columns="60"
        Rows="8"
        runat="server" />

<asp:HtmlEditorExtender
        TargetControlID="txtComments"
        runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
```

But it is giving the error

**Description**: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

**Parser Error Message**: Unknown server tag 'asp:HtmlEditorExtender'.

Help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change TagPrefix

```
  <%@ Register TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"%>
```

and

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="Server" />
```

then

```
<ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender
        TargetControlID="txtComments"
        runat="server" />
```

it should work.

if you have ScriptManager on your master page you don't need to add it on content pages. And also when you using ToolkitScriptManager you don't need defaut ScriptManager.

### UPDATE:

Check in your web config for AjaxControlToolkit tagPrefix as bellow.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

if it is there when you drag and drop controls will insert with correct tag prefix.

try to add ajax toolkit with [nuget](http://nuget.org/), by using Package Manager Console. You can enter the command `Install-Package AjaxControlToolkit` in the console to install the Ajax ControlToolkit

Comment: <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="Server" />


        <asp:TextBox
        ID="txtComments"
        TextMode="MultiLine"
        Columns="60"
        Rows="8"
        runat="server" />
 <ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender
        TargetControlID="txtComments"
        runat="server" />

        </asp:Content>

Answer (score 0):

Try with using the scriptmanager in master page....